# JQuery version 1.11.0 Load Error in Safari 5.1.7 for Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, safari

I have got the below error when loading in Safari 5.1.7 for windows.
The error is as below:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'div.cloneNode( true ).click()')
```

When drill deeper down to jquery 1.11.0 source code, it was pointing to the code below in bold:

```
// IE9-10 clones events bound via attachEvent, but they don't trigger with .click()
    support.noCloneEvent = true;
    if ( div.attachEvent ) {
        div.attachEvent( "onclick", function() {
            support.noCloneEvent = false;
        });

        **div.cloneNode( true ).click();**
    }
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2. It seems that the JQuery failed to be loaded in Safari.

Any idea on why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird. This error only happened in Safari 5.1.7 for Windows.

For some reason, I need to put JQuery script before other scripts even though that other scripts do not use JQuery.

This is resolved by putting JQuery script on top before other scripts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I resolved with [simulate](http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/).

Sample:

```
    // Triggering a native browser event using the simulate plugin
    $( "a" ).simulate( "click" );
```

[Simulate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate/) events to help unit test user interactions. I try  putting JQuery script on top, but not work for me.